# Uncaught Error:Template parse errors: product is not a known element:

Tags: angular2-template

I recently started learning angular2. trying to develop small application while learning from online tutorials. I am facing an error saying,

`Uncaught Error: Template parse errors: 'product' is not a known element:
1. If 'product' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. To allow any element add 'NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component.
ng:///AppModule/AppComponent.html@9:13`

My app.component.ts (in folder app)

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-root',
    template: `<product></product>`
})

export class AppComponent {
    userText: string = 'Good Afternoon';
}
```

My app.module.ts (in folder app)

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { HomeComponent } from './home/home.component';

@NgModule({
    imports: [BrowserModule, FormsModule, HttpModule, 
    RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes)],
    declarations: [AppComponent, HomeComponent],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent],
    providers: [EmployeeService]
})

export class AppModule { }
```

home.component.ts (in home folder)

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'product',
    templateUrl: './home.component.html'
})

export class HomeComponent {
    title = 'Welcome!';
}
```

I wanted to create html page in home.component.html (in home folder) and linked it by templateUrl in home.component.ts, and with the help of selector "product"
I want to put it in display by binding with app.component.ts (in app folder).

Please help me to solve this issue.
Thank you.

Comment: Can you share home.component.html file?

Comment: <div class="container">
    <h1>{{title}}</h1>
</div>

Comment: Try <div class="container"><product><h1>{{title}}</h1></product> </div>

Comment: I am getting the same error.

Comment: @Taru90 Where have you given the <router-outlet></router-outlet> ??